# How to know when the gained focus on the first component is initiated by default when parent component became visible or by users actions

Tags: java, swing

I have a popup component which has a first component JTextComponent and I need to recognize in FocusListener where from the focus gained to this component: when popup appears and the component get focus by default or user clicks on it. I didn't find the way to do it using FocusEvent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming a general use-case, what exactly is it that is tripping you? In my view:

1. Write the code you wish to execute when focus is gained in a method, say *onFocusGained(boolean defaultFocus)*.
2. Call it from the FocusEvent methods with *onFocusGained(true)*.
3. Call it from the MouseAdapter methods with *onFocusGained(false)*.

Comment: I need to have selected text when focus is gained by default but when user clicks on the field the text has not to be selected. So when I have two listeners: Mouse and Focus then on click event both of them are invoked and I see my field is selected for a moment and then selection disappear. It's not good.

Comment: Ok. I understood the problem now. One workaround could be to use boolean flags. Keep a flag in the class to signal that a click event on the field has been initiated. In the focus listener, do not select the text if the flag is set (and reset it back, so that next time mouse event is triggered, it is set again). The only case in which this mechanism will fail, is when the focus listener gets invoked before the Mouse Listener. The workaround to that will be to deselect text, every time the mouse listener is called.

Comment: Eventually, that was good for me to add MouseListener and invoke FocusLictener later using SwingUtilities.invokeLater(). When I have the event my MouseListsner is invoked first and set the flag as true and FocusListener is invoked the second and check if the flag is true. If not so the event was not generated by mouse and should be processed appropriately. And if the flag is true I do nothing only set the flag false again.